# Is there a way to choose between adding/setting an index of an ArrayList depending on if the list is as big as the index or not?

Tags: java, arraylist

Depending on whether the ArrayList contains a 3rd element or not, I need to either replace it, or add on a 3rd element.

What I have currently:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ListReplace {
public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main (String[] args){
    list.add("first");
    list.add("second");
    list.add("third");

    if (list.size() <= 3)
      list.add(3, "newVal");
    else 
      list.set(3, "newVal");
}

}
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this? Did not find anything in the Guava Collections library.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Depending on whether the arraylist contains a 3rd element or not, I need to either replace it, or add on a 3rd element.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes that's right. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Your way looks fine to me, just be careful with the condition on the size.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will work if the element to be inserted is at position less than the size of the List, if the insert position is greater than the size will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at `Runtime`

The below code will add null to the list if the index is less than size

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("One");
    list.add("Two");
    list.add("Three");
    int n = 5;
    if (list.size() >= n) {
        list.add(n, "new Three");
    } else {
        for (int i = list.size(); i < n; i++) {
            list.add(null);
        }
        list.add("new Value");
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

`n = 5 [One, Two, Three, null, null, new Value]
n = 3 [One, Two, Three, new Three]`